# Minecraft skin is the same on LAN networks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I changed the skin on my computer but when i play on lan with a friend on their account i have the same skin as them, and when they play on my server vise versa they have the same skin as my default character...

I simply swapped out the "char.png" with my own custom skin. What do I need to do to make each of us have our own skin on a server?

Comment: Quick question: do you have a paid Minecraft account?

Comment: Alex: If you lost the credentials for your old account, create a new one and flag this post for a moderator with the comment to merge your accounts. With that you can comment here clarifying the situation

Answer (score 5):

Go to [the official Minecraft website](http://minecraft.net), login, and go to the Profile section. There's a spot right there to upload your custom skin, and it will then be downloaded and used by other clients on any server you play on. You can then put back the default skin on your local files, too, since that one is used for every player who hasn't uploaded a custom skin, and you'll probably want them all using the default.

Comment: Assuming they have a paid account, of course.